# Who teaches that God is bound by time?

Tags: philosophy, logic, sovereignty

Edit: The proposed duplicate cannot possibly be a duplicate, because I attempted to clarify the answer to this question in the proposed duplicate's comments, but was told to ask another official question.

---

[This answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89637/56378) follows temporal logic to reason that the Real Presence in the Eucharist is logically impossible:

> Logically, it would be impossible for Jesus to be holding in his hand a piece of bread that had become his broken, sacrificial body, prior to that body having died in sacrifice.

This is a defense of the statement [here](https://normangeisler.com/does-the-nt-support-the-rc-view-of-communion/) by [Norman Geisler](http://normangeisler.com/about/):

> It is not *possible* since Jesus would be holding himself in his own hand (when He said, “this is my body”).

We know that Jesus is not bound by the physics that would prevent a man from walking on water (Matthew 14:25).

Who teaches, and where can one find a defense, that Jesus is bound by the physics of time?

Comment: I don't see any helpful difference or clarification between this and your own (potentially, I suggest, _duplicate_ ) question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89635/is-it-impossible-for-jesus-to-hold-himself-in-his-own-hand)

Comment: I think the argument would state that Jesus, while in the flesh, was bound by time and so, as he held the bread in his as yet un-crucified hand, it was just bread.

Comment: No, the argument I presented in my answer to your almost duplicate Q was that the night before Jesus went to the cross, his body had not yet been broken. In a few hours it would be, but until then, participation in the bread he held in his hand would be that of bread, and not a miraculously changed piece of bread for Christ had not yet died sacrificially. So Augustine's claim was theologically unsound. The Son entering our world in space and time, was exquisitely timed, God using time to achieve his purpose. He created time and is master of it, using it for his own purpose but he also inhabits

Comment: eternity as the Bible states in Isaiah 57:15 – “For thus says the high and lofty One who inhabits eternity, whose name is Holy: I dwell in the high and holy place…” But the Son of God left that high and holy place to enter into time and space as the man, Jesus, at exactly the precise time planned before the world was created. I suggest your question needs to show the difference between God inhabiting the eternal heaven that is his abode, and the Son of God leaving there, to enter into our physical, time-controlled earth. (And thanks for the up-vote!)

Comment: @Anne Jesus says 'The Son (of man) which is in heaven' even as his own feet were on planet earth. And ' ... the only begotten Son which is in the bosom of the Father : he has declared Him'. Thus the Son 'declares' even when 'in the bosom'. Thus his presence in humanity on earth does not (in any way) alter His divine union with the Father in (eternal) heaven.  Faith sees this and appreciates it. Unbelief cannot rise to such things.

Comment: @Nigel  Well put, and a necessary comment to show the inscrutability of the Father and the Son in their unique relationship with each other.

Comment: @Anne - I don't see how this is a duplicate. I didn't know (and, in fact, I still don't think) Geisler was using temporal logic to refute the possibility of Jesus holding himself in his own hand. Also, please re-read his use of Augustine: it appears he's using Augustine to support his argument rather than claiming Augustine is being theologically unsound.

Comment: @MikeBorden - Yes, that's my understanding, that Jesus is being said to be bound by time, while not being bound by other physics such as those that would prevent a man from walking on water or turning water into wine. I'm looking for an online resource with a statement of such a thing, or a defense of it.

Comment: @ken  I appreciate that this is not a full duplicate and have not marked it as such. Geisler explains himself (without any help or hindrance from me!). But my answer to your previous Q was put up here, and I was responding to clarify what I meant, sticking to the event he and Augustine were commenting on – the last supper of the Lord hours before he died as a sacrifice. I see the Godhead as Timelord of the cosmos, entering into time on earth as and when chosen, and leaving at its predetermined moment, but that’s my opinion, my way of looking at it.

Comment: Some related content here:  https://opentheword.org/2019/03/19/was-jesus-referring-to-another-time-dimension/

Comment: Related: transdimensionality explaining billions of timelines of sin experienced and propitiated in a 6-9 hour crucifixion and 2-3 days in the ground.  https://www1.cbn.com/astrophysicist-explains-how-god-not-constrained-time-or-space

Comment: Two words to find in the Bible for a reasonable answer: eternal (no beginning and no end) and everlasting (beginning but no end)